# factorial calculation in C

Tags: c, logic, factorial

I wanted to write a simple program to calculate the factorial of a given number using C. Yet my code seems to have some logical error that I can't detect. Would be glad for help.

```
int fact(int n);
int main(void)
{
    int num = get_int("Type number: ");
    printf("%i\n", fact(num));
}

//define function

int fact(int n)
{

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        n *= i;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: One error: You are changing `n` in the loop and also using it as the termination condition `i < n`. That is, chasing your own tail.

Comment: What is the problem you have with this code? For some specified input, what is the expected and actual output? And have you tried to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement (while monitoring variables and their values) to see what really happens in your program?

Comment: Use a separate variable to hold the result of the multiplications and the loop limit.

Comment: Try writing in a notebook the values of `i` and `n` for some examples and see where it takes you. This is a good skill to acquire early on as it evolves with time. If that fails print `i` and `n` in the loop and compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mathematics, the factorial of a positive integer `N`, denoted by `N!`, is the product of all positive `integers` less than or equal to `N`:

```
N!=N*(N-1)*(N-2)*(N-3)*.......*1
     +-------------------------+
     notice that this is: (N-1)!  <==>  So, N! = N*(N-1)!
```

we can use these mathematical facts to implement the factorial function in 2 different forms, `recursive` and `iterative` approaches:

#### recursive approach

```
size_t rec_factorial(size_t n)
{
    /*Base case or stopping condition*/
    if(n==0)
    {
        /* 0! = 1 */
        return 1;
    }
    /*n! = n * (n-1)!*/
    return n * rec_factorial(n-1);
}
```

#### iterative approach

```
size_t factorial(size_t n)
{
  size_t j = 1;
  size_t result = 1;
  while(j <= n){
    result *= j; /* n!=n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)*....1 */
    ++j;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `n` to calculate.

You have to save total with another variable

```
int fact(int n)
{
    int product = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        product = product  * i;
    }
    return product;
}
```